# We can able to establish connection betwee two gmail user in TOKOX using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, opentok, videochat, tokbox

> I am reviewing about tokbox browser video chat app still i didnt get
>   the answer for that following questions.

```
->By using tokbox we can able to establish connection between 2 or more gmail users.
->tokbox can be used for sending files like the functionality in skype.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tokbox CANNOT be used for sending files like the functionality in skype.
tokbox does not establish connection between 2 or more gmail users.